# ComponentNotFoundException Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

Here is my Installer.cs :

```
class Installer : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container
            .Register(Component.For<IDbContext>()
            .ImplementedBy<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .LifeStyle.PerThread
            );

        container
            .Register(Component.For(typeof(IRepository<>))
            .ImplementedBy(typeof(Repository<>))
            .LifeStyle.PerThread
            );

        container
            .Register(Component.For<IServiceReadCity>()
            .ImplementedBy<ServiceReadCity>()
            .LifeStyle.PerThread
            );
    }
}
```

Here is my Program.cs :

```
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.SqlServerTypesAssemblyName = "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=898989899898989898";

var container = new WindsorContainer();

container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
IServiceReadCity _cityReadService = container.Resolve<IServiceReadCity>();

var cities = _cityReadService.GetListQuery();
```

This is console application. I get this exception :

> {"No component for supporting the service
>   Reveal.Domain.Location.Service.Read.IServiceReadCity was found"}
>    At this line :

```
IServiceReadCity _cityReadService = container.Resolve<IServiceReadCity>();
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you breakpoint your installer to make sure it actually runs? You can also inspect the container during debug to check which services are registered and what implementations are backing them.

Comment: @Charleh I put a breakpoint to the installer and I see that it doesn't run. How can I make it work? Thanks.

Comment: You probably need to make your installer `public`. I'd imagine Windsor scans the assembly for public types implementing the `IWindsorInstaller` interface. Likely Windsor isn't running it because it can't find it.

Comment: You are right. Making installer public solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installers in Windsor need to be publicly accessible as Windsor looks for public types implementing the `IWindsorInstaller` interface.

Making the installer `public` should fix the issue